# codeigniter and wordpress install with nginx but blog internal URL is not working

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, nginx

I have installed the code igniter project on the root directory and WordPress blog in the /blog directory. But the internal pages of blogs are not working. Below is the default file code. Tried all the solution given at the community but it is not working. //example.com/blog/sample-post/ this is not working. But example.com/blog/?p=2 this will work. Any help will be much appreciated

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name www.mydomain.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

ssl_certificate /home/ssl/pte.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/pte.key;
root /var/www/html;

server_name www.mydomain.com;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

if (!-e $request_filename) {
     rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}

location / {
   # First attempt to serve request as file, then
   # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
   #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/?q=$uri&$args;
 }

 location /blog/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php
 }

 # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
   #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 #location ~ /\.ht {
 #   allow all;
  #}

 }
```

Comment: Your configuration file has a missing `;`. You should test it using `nginx -t`

Comment: @RichardSmith added ; but still no success.

Comment: You have a `if (!-e $request_filename)` statement that will prevent your `try_files` rules from working.

Comment: I tried removing that but the code igniter project shows the 500 errors. However, the Wordpress blog internal URL is working.

Comment: Your first `try_files` statement redirects to `/index.php/?q=$uri&$args` which isn't currently handled correctly. To match the `rewrite` statement you just removed, you should try: `/index.php$is_args$args`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RichardSmith It worked like a charm. I was muddling around on this for two days and finally, you provided a solution. Once again thanks